# How to assign a user (string value) to each Mongo documents?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

There are four users "AB", "BC", "CD", "EF" and a hundred thousand Mongo documents in the collection.

There is *key* called "AssignedTo" with empty *value* for all documents.

```
{"AssignedTo":""}
```

How can I assign those users sequentially  in fair manner to > 100 000 of data in Spring Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo shell comes with feature of executing JavaScript code inside it. The below solution updates the document's AssignedTo using Round Robin strategy.

Login into MongoShell and connect with the required db and then execute the following commands

```
> var counter = 0
> db.collectionName.find({}).forEach( function(thisDoc) {
... if (counter % 4 == 0) {
... db.collectionName.update({_id: thisDoc._id}, {$set: {"AssignedTo": "AB"}});
... } else if (counter % 4 == 1) {
... db.collectionName.update({_id: thisDoc._id}, {$set: {"AssignedTo": "BC"}});
... } else if (counter % 4 == 2) {
... db.collectionName.update({_id: thisDoc._id}, {$set: {"AssignedTo": "CD"}});
... } else if (counter % 4 == 3) {
... db.collectionName.update({_id: thisDoc._id}, {$set: {"AssignedTo": "EF"}});
... }
... counter = counter + 1;
... })
```